Story about a boy and other kids who went into jungle to spend holidays
Story begins with a boy(lead character) who went into jungle with other kids and teacher(s) to spend some holidays in jungle. He(lead character) was suffering from some kind of ailment, which made him timid(not sure), quite reserved, usually sad and ignored by others.
After some days in jungle, there was some kind of insects attack on their camp in which that boy(lead character) in spite of that ailment comes out and fight with bravery against these insects and became the hero.
I think he used fire to kill these insects.
That movie is old and made before 2004.

Starspeed, if you're still around, I think you're looking for Ticks (AKA Infested AKA C2) with Seth Green from 1993: City teens in a wilderness field trip are attacked by insects, and the hero is a troubled, traumatized red-headed boy (Green). The entire movie is available on Youtube, and in a scene in 50:14 and onwards, Clint Howard is eaten by bugs from the inside and asks a girl to shoot him with his gun.

Based on the description this film comes to mind: The Blue Butterfly. It seems to match the description based on what I remember regarding the boy's ailment.  

Thanks for quick response.
But it was not that movie. The movie "The Blue Butterfly" you mentioned was released in 2004 and it not really was that movie. The movie i am talking about way released 5 to 20 years back from 2004 and it was about "INSECTS".

I have now recalled some more features about that movie. I think that boy was not really kid but a teenager. Maybe he was traumatized by his father so that's why he had the above mentioned mental illness. The movie had some high graphic scenes.
In one of the scenes, a man was badly eaten by insects from inside and he was holding a gun in his hands and saying to someone, "Kill me....".
